# Stone like deposit at the bottom of the waste pipes

Tags: plumbing

One 100 mm pipe collects waste from two toilets. Lately I'm having problems;  I could hear the waste flowing randomly so I decided to cut through the PVC.

Here is what I found (I broke this part off, this is what the bottom part the inside of the pipe is):[image]
[image]

I was able to clean the pipes using an implement that plugs on my high pressure cleaner, but the pipes are still filled with those deposit.

What are they called, should I try to remove them, and if so, how can I remove them.

It's really dense, and even smaller parts that broke off won't just flow with the water.

The smooth part is the bottom part, and the rough one is the top one.

This does not react with vinegar: no foaming, no softening.

The cross section is similar to an oyster's . You can see the stratums.

Also, the slope is wrong: there is one section of 5 meters that is perfectly horizontal, then a T junction,  then 5 meters with a 1 cm / m slope..

Comment: Calcium (or other mineral) deposits is my first guess.  Do you have hard water?  Snap of a bit and put it in some vinegar.  Does it dissolve and/or get softer?

Comment: Water is hard; also the water softener (2 filters and 1 large salt container) has a small tube that rejects elements upsteam into that same pipe. The vinegar had no effect on a sample of that material. No foaming, no softening at all after 48 hours.

Comment: The ['drain tube'](https://www.premierwatermn.com/water-softener-service-drain-line-problems/), I suppose?  I'm out of my depth here.  I have no experience with water softeners but it seems plausible that is where it's coming from.

Comment: It is my understanding that this device is removing  Ca2+ and Mg2+ from the water and dumping it in the waste pipe, and they are replaced by Na+ in the water, making it softer. So my feeling was that the water running in that pipe was not only hard, but  even harder with those extranneous Ca2+ rejected from the softener, making the situation even worse ( toilet water being hard / not treated)

Comment: Seems plausible to me.  The other thing I think might matter is the slope on the waste or perhaps downstream blockages allowing crud to settle.  The mystery is why is it breaking away?  Do you have any water hammer problems esp. with toilet drains?

Comment: No mystery. I broke it myself because I needed  a sample.. Also, a few other smaller pieces broke away after I cleaned it with the pressure cleaner.

Comment: I thought you found loose pieces blocking the pipe.  My mistake.

Comment: I would be very concerned about the slope issues. Is the pipe easily accessible (ie in basement or crawlspace?). I think if this is addressed, the other issue may resolve itself or at least, not grow worse.

Comment: I believe it is grout that was dumped into the sewer when the tile guys had a bunch left over

Comment: That's what I was thinking, something dumped down the toilet that should not have been. My kids did that with some unknown school project goop that solidified in the pipes, it made me have to replace them. (The pipes, not the kids...)

Comment: Is that purple glitter I see mixed in the layers???I also think it looks like grout or cement. When I worked in a stained glass studio, some of our students would dump grout from mosaics down the drain despite being told not to. That’s pretty much what the pipe looked like when the plumber cut it away a few years later...including the glitter! If it’s grout then muriatic acid should make a dent in it. Not sure if that stuff is safe for pipes tho. It’s pretty nasty. Wear gloves!